# Prompt that is shown when deleting question that has duplicates

Tags: discussion, feature-request

When casting a delete vote on the question [*How to make array from array by using some seperator?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480194/how-to-make-array-from-array-by-using-some-seperator) (possibly 10K only), I was prompted by this dialog:

[image]

For another question to be a duplicate of this lowly rated question, it is probably the same question repeated by the same person, but I prefer to check it before continuing with my action. To that end, this dialog serves a good purpose but it doesn't empower me - I have to quit out of the dialog and manually find (and check) the duplicate question before deleting the current question.

**Suggestion:** include a link to the duplicate question in the text of the dialog, that way I can navigate to it in a separate browser tab and review it before deciding whether to continue with my delete vote.

Comment: Even better: make the popup _display_ the duplicate, the way the close dialog does.